# Swift JSON Parsing Wunderground

Tags: json, swift, parsing

i am a beginner with swift an Progrmamming i need values from the JSON it looks Like this:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "astronomy": 1
  }
    }
        ,   "moon_phase": {
        "percentIlluminated":"23",
        "ageOfMoon":"5",
        "phaseofMoon":"Erstes Viertel",
        "hemisphere":"North",
        "current_time": {
        "hour":"8",
        "minute":"28"
        },
        "sunrise": {
        "hour":"6",
        "minute":"55"
        },
        "sunset": {
        "hour":"19",
        "minute":"50"
        },
        "moonrise": {
        "hour":"9",
        "minute":"50"
        },
        "moonset": {
        "hour":"0",
        "minute":"06"
        }
    },
    "sun_phase": {
        "sunrise": {
        "hour":"6",
        "minute":"55"
        },
        "sunset": {
        "hour":"19",
        "minute":"50"
        }
    }
}
```

i will get the hour & minute from sunset and sunrise to a variable!

my code :

```
 var sunriseHour: [String] = []
    var sunriseMinute: [String] = []
    var sunsetHour: [String] = []
    var sunsetMinute: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url=URL(string:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/dbd539bd631e/astronomy/lang:DL/q/DL/iphofen.json")
        do {
            let allData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = data["moon_phase"] {


                        if let sunriseData = arrJSON["sunrise"]{



                print(sunriseData)
                                        }
                if let sunsetData = arrJSON["sunset"]{

             print(sunsetData)
                }
           }
            print("hour: ",sunriseHour)
            print("minute: ",sunriseMinute)
            print("hour: ",sunsetHour)
            print("minute: ",sunsetMinute)


        }
        catch {

        }

            }
```

i get with print(sunriseData) and print(sunsetData) the right data from this :

> Optional({
>       hour = 6;
>       minute = 55; }) Optional({
>       hour = 19;
>       minute = 50; }) hour:  [] minute:  [] hour:  [] minute:  []

How do i get it in the variable sunriseHour, sunriseMinute, sunsetHour, sunsetMinute..

thanks from your help..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `hour` and `minute` values are (single) `String` not `[String]` (array).

Declare all variables as empty strings

```
var sunriseHour = ""
var sunriseMinute = ""
var sunsetHour = ""
var sunsetMinute = ""
```

Then do not load data synchronously from a remote URL, use always an asynchronous way:

```
       let url = URL(string:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/dbd539bd631e/astronomy/lang:DL/q/DL/iphofen.json")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    guard let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!) as? [String:Any],
                          let moonPhase = jsonData["moon_phase"] as? [String:Any] else { return }

                    let sunrise = moonPhase["sunrise"] as! [String:String]
                    let sunset = moonPhase["sunset"] as! [String:String]

                    sunriseHour = sunrise["hour"]!
                    sunriseMinute = sunrise["minute"]!

                    sunsetHour = sunset["hour"]!
                    sunsetMinute = sunset["minute"]!

                    print("Sunrise - \(sunriseHour):\(sunriseMinute)"
                    print("Sunset - \(sunsetHour):\(sunsetMinute)"

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

The data for `sunrise` and `sunset` are in dictionaries derived from `moon_phase`. All values are forced unwrapped because sunrise and sunset are supposed to exist every day ;-)

PS : Consider to define more descriptive variable names, `arrJSON` is not very meaningful.

Comment: You are my Hero... :-) Thanks